# Which qualitative method is best used with Empathy approach?

Tags: user-research, user-centered-design, personas, qualitative-analysis

I have recently been doing a research that involved focus-group, interview, observation and lastly a survey as data gathering and analysis of user behavioral, emotions, experience. I have read and understood what empathy means and concluded on my report the findings of what patients' feel, see, hear and do.

My question is : which method suits the above description and why :

1. Ethnography.
2. Action Research.

Comment: Please give us more details on the domain. What do you want to research exactly? How much empaty patients show to doctors or to technology ? Please, give more details.

Comment: Research about : 
The use of behavioral strategies to change patient's behavioral and attitude towards healthy eating.

Areas of interest : User-centered design, Consumer health technology, cultural-relevant design.

To find: pain-points, activity, experience, emotions, behavioral and psychological aspects of patients. 

I did a comprehensive literature about the topic, found the problem, state the objectives. The demographic study was conducted and learned about the target-audiences and other methods were conducted " including meeting with dietitians and other specialists".

Comment: Very cool research topic!!

Answer (score 1):

Ethnography traditionally involves long-term observations of a culture, and Action Research is understood as when you want to invite research into your actual project.

I think for your research environment setup, especially if you have a specific project, demographic study, focus group, etc., you are leaning towards Action Research instead of Ethnography.

Comment: Thank you Wen .My question would be : Which is suited for empathy approach " Action research or Ethnography " ?

Comment: I think empathic research approach incorporate applied ethnography more than action research (for example, observation,interview,and conversation with real people) (see this article is your need more details http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3575059/).

Comment: Thank you Wen. I have read that research before. I also did interview, observation, conversation and focus group. Based on what I read the most suited is EAR "Ethnograhpy action research". :)